# Manter data source de gridview no post-back

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um gridview que é preenchido por um web-service com dado vindos do SAP. Pode retornar até 2000 linha com 30 colunas.
Este conteúdo é sempre o mesmo, então ao executar o web-service 10 vezes vai sempre retornar o mesmo conteúdo.
Este grid é exibido para o usuário onde poderá ser aplicado filtros e ordenação através dos cabeçalhos das colunas. 
Posso salvar o DataTable (ou list) do data source do grid no viewstate e efetuar os filtros e ordenação.
Só que o viewstate acaba estourando.
Teria como manter/salvar este conteúdo no post-back, para poder filtrar e ordenar?
Porque não faz sentido executar o webservice novamente, demora e é sempre o mesmo retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ViewState` seria realmente a primeira opção a se tentar, a segunda seria tentar trabalhar com a `Session`.

Uma outra opção recomendada, seria você fazer o `Cache` dessa consulta e daí utilizá-lo sempre que necessário.

Comment: Session também não dá pois onde o sistema roda,ele já esta em produção, eles limitam o tamanho das Sessions. Sobre o Cache, só queira confirmar se não teria outra solução, antes verificar a possibilidade de usá-lo.

Comment: Vc poderia fazer uma temp table no seu db também. 'Outra' solução, mas um tanto quanto (me permito o uso dessa palavra) inviável... seria de salvar um arquivo fisico e reconsultar esse arquivo.

Comment: também acho que seria a solução simples e correta. Mas  gravar no bd não posso, o sistema já esta em produção, a empresa é cheia de burocracia. Então ao adicionar mais uma tabela no bd seria considerado melhoria. E o processo depende avaliação de risco, previsão de caixa e licitação. Já uma alteração no código pode ser considerada manutenção. Até pensei em salvar o DataTable como xml. Só que teria de ficar na  pasta de cookies, pois pelo que sei é o único lugar onde posso gravar usando uma aplicação web. Só achei que seria muita gambiarra. kkk

Comment: Senta e chora então pq na sua situação meu amigo, acho que seria o ideal por agora kkk... brincadeiras a parte a manutenção vou terá q fazer de um jeito ou de outro. Pensei em algo que seria completamente estranho de se fazer... contudo,todavia,entretando né... pensei de vc serializar o retorno e colocar num hiddenField ou div oculta O_O.

Comment: kkkk... Cada solução fica mais estranha que a original. Realmente é uma situação conturbada e cheia de meandros. Acho que vou começar com o cache e depois testar as outras soluções discutidas aqui. Acho que pior que esta não pode ficar, ou pode? kkk... Se não for possível solucionar ficará como esta. Agradeço as dicas. Valeu!

Comment: nunca diga que pior do que está não fica... lembre-se que Murphy está a solta. Mas vai lá, testar é sempre o melhor meio pra solucionar um problema.

Comment: Vou testar mesmo! Só queria ver se não estava deixando de avaliar alguma outra opção. Obrigado! E realmente é chorar.